# ScrollView works fine until I've fetched an image and update my view

Tags: swiftui, combine

I was fooling around with SwiftUI and Combine on my iPad's Swift playgrounds and trying to print out the communication details between `Combine` publishers and subscribers to `MyConsole`.

At first, I put some placeholder text into `MyConsole` and showed it in a `ScrollView`, and it scrolled without any problem.

[image: scroll view]

Then I tapped the "Get Image" button to fetch an image from the internet, and the network request was perfectly successful too:

[image: image fetched]

But now comes the problem: my `ScrollView` stops to scroll, it suddenly freezes. If I tap the "Reset" button to reset my `ContentView`, the `ScrollView` functions normally, it is able to scroll again.

Could anyone take a look at my following code, and tell me what was wrong with my `ScrollView`? Thanks.

```
import Combine
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport

class MyConsole: TextOutputStream, ObservableObject {
    
    @Published private(set) var text = ""
    
    // TextOutputStream
    public func write(_ string: String) { text += string }
    
    public static let shared = MyConsole()
    private init() {}
    
    public func clear(to text: String = "") { self.text = text }
}

// long text for ScrollView
let string = (1...40)
    .map{ _ in "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.\n" }
    .joined()

let url = URL(string: "https://source.unsplash.com/random")!
let console = MyConsole.shared

// performs a network request to fetch a random image from Unsplash’s public API
func imagePub() -> AnyPublisher<Image?, Never> {
    URLSession.shared
        .dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
        .map { data, _ in Image(uiImage: UIImage(data: data)!)}
        .print("image", to: console)  // print to MyConsole
        .replaceError(with: nil)
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}

// ViewModel
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var image: Image?
    let taps = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()  // simulate user taps on a button
    var subscriptions = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    
    init() {
        console.clear(to: string)
        taps
            .map { _ in imagePub() }  // map the tap to a new network request
            .switchToLatest()         // accept only the latest tap
            .assign(to: \.image, on: self)
            .store(in: &subscriptions)
    }
    
    // user intent
    func getImage() { taps.send() }
}

// ContentView
struct ContentView: View {
    
    // view model
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = ViewModel()
    @ObservedObject var console = MyConsole.shared
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            
            // image
            viewModel.image?
                .resizable().scaledToFit()
                .frame(height: 300).border(Color.black)
            
            // console
            ScrollView {
                Text(console.text)
            }// ScrollView
                .frame(height: 200).padding()
                .border(Color.black)
                .background(Color.purple)
            
            // button
            HStack {
                Button(action: {
                    self.viewModel.getImage()
                }, label: {
                    Text("Get Image")
                        .padding().foregroundColor(.white)
                        .background(Color.blue).cornerRadius(12)
                })
                Button(action: {
                    self.viewModel.image = nil
                    self.console.clear(to: string)
                }, label: {
                    Text("Reset")
                        .padding().foregroundColor(.white)
                        .background(Color.pink).cornerRadius(12)
                })
            }
            
        }.padding().background(Color.gray).shadow(radius: 8)
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(ContentView())
```

Comment: Maybe it's because of Playgrounds? I remember having issues myself once.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what's causing your problem, but you should use `@StateObject` instead of `@ObservedObject` for storing `viewModel` to indicate that the object is "owned" by this view. Technically SwiftUI is free to re-create your view as many times as it wants, and using `@ObservedObject` means the view model will be newly created each time. `@StateObject` will ensure it's only created once.

Comment: Also, you may have to add `.receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)` in `imagePub` to make sure the UI is updated on the main thread. That could be the issue.